# Pyomo: How to pass None as parameter value

Tags: python, pyomo

This is hopefully an easy question to answer.  I'm trying to create a model that allows the user to pass None for a parameter value.  This is so that they can define the upper/lower bound, or choose to have no bound.  An example problem (diet problem) with set/param definitions, AMPL style data file section, and constraint function are below:

**Set/Param Defs**

```
model.Ingredients = pyo.Set()
model.Properties = pyo.Set()
model.IngredientProperties = pyo.Param(model.Ingredients, model.Properties)
model.MinProperty = pyo.Param(model.Properties, within=pyo.Any)
model.MaxProperty = pyo.Param(model.Properties, within=pyo.Any)
```

**Data File Section**

```
set Ingredients := Banana Milk Yogurt ;
set Properties := Fat Protein Carbs ;
param:  MinProperty  MaxProperty :=
      Fat  0.009       0.013
  Protein  0.200        None
    Carbs   None       0.070;
param IngredientProperties:    Fat    Protein  Carbs :=
                    Banana    0.375    0.020   0.010
                      Milk    0.003    0.075   0.015
                    Yogurt    0.015    0.650   0.075;
```

**Constraint Function**

```
def _property_constraint_rule(model, p):
    return (model.MinProperty[p], sum(
        model.IngredientProperties[i, p]
        * model.Blend[i]
        for i in model.Ingredients
        ), model.MaxProperty[p])
```

Unfortunately, when I try this, I get the error message: `TypeError: Cannot treat the value 'None' as a constant.`  Is there another way to define parameters as None?  I know that I could just use huge positive / negative numbers, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: like it says, the issue is with mixing none and constants.  if you encapsulated all the constant numbers in some type of class, then None might be treated as valid, but thats a lot more work than needed.  In your case, I recommend checking out math.inf and 0.0 (your properties dont go negative) which are constants.

Comment: math.inf will not work in this case -> when put in a file, it will be read in as a string.  So that will throw the same error as well, unless I made my own method for reading in a data file to pyomo, which seems very overkill

Comment: Some builtin floating point reading methods interpret "Inf"; not sure this one does - a lot of it's figuring out what to call it.  Still it looks like you have a better solution with a default value of None!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to go forward with an Abstract model, I think you are stuck using a default value, which is fine.  If you were using a concrete model, you could conditionally construct the constraint because the data is known at time of construction.

Also, in your data file, you need to represent None values in this format as a period `.`.  If you use the word 'None' it will barf as it is not recognized as Python's `None`

This trial build worked fine for me...

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.AbstractModel()

model.Ingredients = pyo.Set()
model.Properties = pyo.Set()
model.IngredientProperties = pyo.Param(model.Ingredients, model.Properties)
model.MinProperty = pyo.Param(model.Properties, within=pyo.Any, default=0.0)
model.MaxProperty = pyo.Param(model.Properties, within=pyo.Any, default=100)

model.Blend = pyo.Var(model.Ingredients, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)


def _property_constraint_rule(model, p):
    return (model.MinProperty[p], sum(
        model.IngredientProperties[i, p] * model.Blend[i]
        for i in model.Ingredients), model.MaxProperty[p])
model.c1 = pyo.Constraint(model.Properties, rule=_property_constraint_rule)

data = pyo.DataPortal()
data.load(filename='data.dat')

instance = model.create_instance(data)

instance.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
3 Set Declarations
    IngredientProperties_index : Dim=0, Dimen=2, Size=9, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        Virtual
    Ingredients : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        ['Banana', 'Milk', 'Yogurt']
    Properties : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=None
        ['Carbs', 'Fat', 'Protein']

3 Param Declarations
    IngredientProperties : Size=9, Index=IngredientProperties_index, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key                   : Value
          ('Banana', 'Carbs') :  0.01
            ('Banana', 'Fat') : 0.375
        ('Banana', 'Protein') :  0.02
            ('Milk', 'Carbs') : 0.015
              ('Milk', 'Fat') : 0.003
          ('Milk', 'Protein') : 0.075
          ('Yogurt', 'Carbs') : 0.075
            ('Yogurt', 'Fat') : 0.015
        ('Yogurt', 'Protein') :  0.65
    MaxProperty : Size=3, Index=Properties, Domain=Any, Default=100, Mutable=False
        Key   : Value
        Carbs :  0.07
          Fat : 0.013
    MinProperty : Size=3, Index=Properties, Domain=Any, Default=0.0, Mutable=False
        Key     : Value
            Fat : 0.009
        Protein :   0.2

1 Var Declarations
    Blend : Size=3, Index=Ingredients
        Key    : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        Banana :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
          Milk :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals
        Yogurt :     0 :  None :  None : False :  True : NonNegativeReals

1 Constraint Declarations
    c1 : Size=3, Index=Properties, Active=True
        Key     : Lower : Body                                                          : Upper : Active
          Carbs :   0.0 :  0.01*Blend[Banana] + 0.015*Blend[Milk] + 0.075*Blend[Yogurt] :  0.07 :   True
            Fat : 0.009 : 0.375*Blend[Banana] + 0.003*Blend[Milk] + 0.015*Blend[Yogurt] : 0.013 :   True
        Protein :   0.2 :   0.02*Blend[Banana] + 0.075*Blend[Milk] + 0.65*Blend[Yogurt] : 100.0 :   True

8 Declarations: Ingredients Properties IngredientProperties_index IngredientProperties MinProperty MaxProperty Blend c1
```

#### Modified `data.dat`

```
set Ingredients := Banana Milk Yogurt ;
set Properties := Fat Protein Carbs ;
param:  MinProperty  MaxProperty :=
      Fat  0.009        0.013
  Protein  0.200        .
    Carbs  .            0.070;
param IngredientProperties:    Fat    Protein  Carbs :=
                    Banana    0.375    0.020   0.010
                      Milk    0.003    0.075   0.015
                    Yogurt    0.015    0.650   0.075;
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes default is what I needed - I tried using `.`, but that wasn't working since I had not defined a default.

Comment: Can you slightly change your answer?  The default value of 100.0 can be changed to `None`, which would be better for both answering the question and in an actual abstract model implementation, where the data params may be unknown.